# pandas dataframe groupby apply multi columns and get count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a excel like this:

| year | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 12 | 23 |
| 2021 | 31 | 0 |
| 2021 | 15 | 21 |
| 2021 | 14 | 0 |
| 2022 | 32 | 0 |
| 2022 | 24 | 15 |
| 2022 | 28 | 29 |
| 2022 | 33 | 0 |

I wanna get count of condition: a>=30 and b==0 group by year
the final output like this:

2021 1

2022 2

I wanna use pandas dataframe to implement this, can anyone help? I'm quite new to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For count matched rows chain both conditions by `&` for bitwise `AND` and aggregate `sum`, `True`s are processing like `1` and `False` like `0`:

```
df1 = ((df.a>=30) & (df.b==0)).astype(int)
           .groupby(df['year']).sum().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
   year  count
0  2021      1
1  2022      2
```

Similar idea with helper column:

```
df1 = (df.assign(count = ((df.a>=30) & (df.b==0)).astype(int))
         .groupby('year', as_index=False)['count']
         .sum())
```

Comment: I tried this way, but it give output like this：
0  2020  False
1  2021  False, it doesn't print count, but True False

Comment: @Liem - what is `print (df[['a','b']].dtypes)` ?

Comment: a int64 b float64

Comment: @Liem - Hmmm,it is correct. I add `.astype(int)` for both solutions, can you test now?

Comment: seems right, so now I get that df1, how do I get the count of a specific year. something like this: df1['2021] get 1