# pandas dataframe groupby get count by multi column condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a excel like this:

| year | month | day | time | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 00：00 | 12 | 23 | 12 |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 01：00 | 31 | 0 | 13 |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | ... | ... | ... | 14 |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 23:00 | ... | ... | 23 |
| 2020 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | 24 |
| 2020 | 12 | 31 | 23:00 | 32 | 0 | 35 |
| 2021 | 1 | 1 | 01：00 | 31 | 0 | 46 |
| 2021 | 1 | 1 | ... | ... | ... | 56 |
| 2021 | 1 | 1 | 23:00 | ... | ... | 45 |
| 2021 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | 34 |
| 2021 | 12 | 31 | 23:00 | 32 | 0 | 45 |

I wanna get data: the sum of c for the row that a >= 30 and b==0 group by year
notice that as long as there's time that fulfill a >= 30 and b==0，we can count this day

I wanna use pandas dataframe to implement this, can anyone help? I'm quite new to python

Comment: Can you add expected otput for see difference with [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72039325/2901002) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, one will need to read the data.

If by "excel" you mean a `.xlsx` file, considering that the file is named `data.xlsx`, read the file into a dataframe with [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) as

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
```

If by "excel" you mean a `.csv` file, assuming the file is named `data.csv`, read the file into a dataframe with [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) as

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Once you have the Excel data into a dataframe, now it is time to run queries on top of that.

In order to get a dataframe with only the rows where a>= 30 and b== 0, do the following

```
df2 = df1[(df1['a'] >= 30) & (df1['b'] == 0)]
```

Now, considering that you want to order by year, month and day ([as you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72039802/pandas-dataframe-groupby-get-count-by-multi-column-condition/72039918?noredirect=1#comment127291728_72039918)), one can generate a new column in the dataframe using [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) as

```
df3['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2[['year', 'month', 'day']])
```

Then, using the new dataframe, that was filtered above and to which we added a new column, one can group by variable/column `date` using [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then sum the values of the column/variable `c` with [`pandas.DataFrame.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) as

```
df4['sum_c'] = df3.groupby('date')['c'].sum()
```

The final dataframe would be `df4`, and to print it

```
print(df4)
```

**Note:** To make it easier for you to understand, anytime one is doing a major change, one is creating a new dataframe.

Comment: I think the group by should be ['year', 'month', 'day'], not only ['day']. And sorry, I missed one condition, there's also a column 'c'，As long as one row fullfill the condition，get the sum of 'c'

Comment: @Liem already updated the answer considering your new requirements.

Answer (score 0):

First filter rows by condition in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then aggregate `sum` for column `c`:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month','day']])
df1 = df[(df.a>=30) & (df.b==0)].groupby('datetime', as_index=False)['c'].sum()
```

Comment: I've modified the problem, I wanna get the sum of c

Comment: @Liem - answer was changed.

Comment: It's quite difficult to explain, imagine one situcation: a represents tempreature, b represents wind speed, c represents the probability of sunshine. So first group by year, in one year, get the sum of probabilities that fullfill wind speed = 0 and tempreature > 30. as you can see in the column, one row is a hour, as long as one hour fullfill our conditions, I can count this days's probability(that is the value of column c). the output is: one year one data

Comment: @Liem - hmmm, I think the best is add expected ouput from sample data for me.